# myArray.push(jQuery) not pushing anything into array

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to solve this part of my coding riddle.

Codes #1 - Select Box > change color:

```
function myFunction(id){
myClass(id);
selectedChecker(id);
}

//FUNCTION TO CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR ONCE SELECTED
function myClass(id){
var displayCheckedIcon = '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
var currentClass = jQuery(".currentIcon"+id);

//TOGGLE THE COLOR CLASS
jQuery(".slotRow"+id).toggleClass("selectedCell tbselection"); 

//TOGGLE TO WHITE FONT CLASS ONCE SELECTED
jQuery(".fontCurrent"+id).toggleClass("fontColorSelected fontOriginal"); 

//CONDITION TO DISPLAY THE 'CHECKED' ICON ONCE CLICKED
if (currentClass.hasClass('uncheckedIcon')) {
    jQuery(".currentIcon"+id).toggleClass("checkedIcon uncheckedIcon");
    jQuery(".currentIcon"+id).html(displayCheckedIcon);
}
else if(currentClass.hasClass("checkedIcon")) {
    jQuery(".currentIcon"+id).toggleClass("uncheckedIcon checkedIcon");
    jQuery(".currentIcon"+id).html("");
  }
}
```

[Before and After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6tua.png)

Codes #2 - Push ID into array:

```
function selectedChecker(id){
var selectedClass = jQuery(".slotRow"+id);
jQuery(selectedClass).each(function(){
    // CHECK IF GOT SELECTED, PUSH ID INTO ARRAY
    if(jQuery(selectedClass).hasClass("selectedCell")){
        var data = []; //ARRAY TO STORE SLOT ID 
        data.push((selectedClass).attr("id"));
        return jQuery(selectedClass);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Codes #3 - The HTML codes (loop):

```
<td id="<?php echo $iSlotId;?>" align="center" style="width:30%;" bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>" onclick="myFunction(id)" name="arrCheckboxSlot[]" class="f_13 gray3 tbselection slotRow<?php echo $iSlotId;?>" value="<?php echo $iSlotId;?>">
  <input name="arrCourtId[]" value="<?php echo $iCourtId;?>" type="hidden">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="f_13 gray3 fontOriginal fontCurrent<?php echo $iSlotId;?>" style="text-decoration:none; font-size:12px;"><?php echo $sSlotName;?>&nbsp;<span  id="<?php echo $iSlotId;?>"  class="currentIcon<?php echo $iSlotId;?> uncheckedIcon"></span></a>
</td>
```

The problem is that, once I clicked the box, the push function doesn't work. It does not push anything into my array.

[image: Output that I got from Bugzilla]

What is my mistake?

Comment: 1) You're creating a new array in every iteration of `each()` 2) your `return` statement is redundant as it returns from the `each()` handler, not from the `selectedChecker()` function

Comment: Hi there! So based on your opinion, what should I do to stop creating those new array in every iteration? I'm still clueless.

Comment: I added an answer for you, although it's a little bit of a guess as to what you're trying to do as the result you're expecting isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot on your quick reply to my answer. Although once I tried your answer but still, not working. I'll try to play around with tips that you gave me. Thanks a lot Rory! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, however you're creating a new array in every iteration of `each()`, and you're also returning from the `each()` function handler, not the parent function.

You can simplify the logic using `filter()` and `map()`. Try this:

```
function selectedChecker(id) {
  var selectedClass = $(".slotRow" + id);
  return $(selectedClass).filter('.selectedCell').map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get(); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to create a facility booking function. There'll be list of slots that user can choose upon. So the scenario is that:

1) User choose booking slot (as you can see in the image 1)

2) Once clicked, supposedly the selectedChecker function should go through each row and check for the selectedCell class. If there's selectedCell, then it will store the bookingID into array. Once submit button clicked, it will send all the element in array to php file

Comment: Well this should build the array for you. You'll just need to then send it in the AJAX request

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed I missed `.` on the class selector. Try the updated version

Comment: I tried it out but still not working. By the way, I just edited the post by including the output print-screen that I got using Bugzilla. Perhaps, it'll give  some ideas on what's wrong with my codes.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 function selectedChecker(id){
    var data = []; //ARRAY TO STORE SLOT ID 
    var selectedClass = jQuery(".slotRow"+id);
    jQuery(selectedClass).each(function(){
        // CHECK IF GOT SELECTED, PUSH ID INTO ARRAY
        if(jQuery(selectedClass).hasClass("selectedCell")){

            data.push((selectedClass).attr("id"));
            return jQuery(selectedClass);
        }
      }); 
    }
```